# Scala : Code for pattern match

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have a code written by some one else. Can you help me to understand this piece of code?

```
 def sameCodeForTwoYears(list: List[(LocalDate, String)]):  List[(LocalDate, String)] = {
 list match {
  case x :: Nil => List.empty
  case x :: xs => if (xs.head._1.minusYears(2).isAfter(x._1) && x._2 == xs.head._2) {
    List(x, xs.head)
  } else sameCodeForTwoYears(xs)
  case Nil => List.empty
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scalas `List[+T]` is an abstract class, implemented by two concrete classes:

1. `Nil` - Representing an empty list
2. `Cons` (`::`) - Represents a linked list with a `head` of type `T` and a `tail` of type `List[+T]`.

The pattern match you see here basically represents these two constructs. Let's do a by case analysis:

```
case x :: Nil => List.empty
```

Means "if `head` is non empty and `tail` is an empty list, return an `List.empty`", which returns an empty list.

```
case x :: xs => if (xs.head._1.minusYears(2).isAfter(x._1) && x._2 == xs.head._2) {
List(x, xs.head)
```

Means "if both `head` and `tail` are non-empty". The predicates following the match basically look into the tuple stored inside the `List[(LocalDateTime, String)]` where `_1` represents the first element and `_2` represents the second element. We dig a little deeper into the meaning if the condition:

```
xs.head._1.minusYears(2).isAfter(x._1)
```

Means "take the first element from tail (`xs`, it's head), look into the first element in the tuple and subtract it by 2 years. If the first element in `x`s tuple (which is a `LocalDateTime`) is after that time.

And

```
x._2 == xs.head._2
```

Means "look into the heads (`x`) second element, which is a `String`, and match it to the next element which is the tails (`xs`) first element (`xs.head`) and match both strings for equality.

Finally:

```
case Nil => List.empty
```

Means "if the list is empty", return an empty list.

Comment: thanx,. Nice explanation

Answer (score 0):

See:
http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/pattern-matching.html
and
http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html

It basically take in a list of a date: LocalDate and and code: String.
If this list is empty or contains one element it returns an empty list.
If neither of the above apply it looks at the first two elements of the list, we shall call them y and z. If y's is after (z's date - 2 years) and y and z's codes are the same it returns a list of y and z.